# why is showing '<groups' with the symbol '<' in NoReverseMatch at /groups/

Tags: python, django

When i type http://127.0.0.1:8000/groups/ to the browser, I get NoReverseMatch at /groups/ and'

[image]

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/groups/
>
> Django Version: 2.2.5 Python Version: 3.8.0 Installed Applications:
>   ['groups',  'django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'bootstrap3',  'accounts',  'posts'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Template error: In template
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\fullstack\django\simplesocialatom\simplesocial\templates\base.html,
>   error at line 12    '    4 :       5
>   :         6 :     Star Social
>   7 :     8 :         9 :
>       10 :     11 :      
>   12 :         13 :     14 :         15 :         16 :     17 :         18 :         19 :     20 :         21 :
>       22 :
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py"
>   in reverse
>     75.                 extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]
>
> During handling of the above exception ('
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     143.                 response = response.render()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py"
>   in render
>     106.             self.content = self.rendered_content
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py"
>   in rendered_content
>     83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py"
>   in render
>     61.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     171.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in _render
>     163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     904.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in _render
>     163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     904.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in _render
>     163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     904.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     904.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     904.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     309.                 return nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render
>     937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     904.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     443.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\simplesocialenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py"
>   in reverse
>     86.                     raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
>
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /groups/ Exception Value: '

And here is my related source code:

project.urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    path('groups/', include('groups.urls', namespace='groups')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('test/', views.TestPage.as_view(), name='test'),
    path('thanks/', views.ThanksPage.as_view(), name='thanks'),
    path('posts/', include('posts.urls'), name='posts'),
]
```

projects settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'groups',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'accounts',
    'posts',
]
```

groups.urls.py file

```
# GROUPS URLS.PY
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from . import views

app_name = 'groups'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ListGroups.as_view(), name='all'),
    path('new/', views.CreateGroup.as_view(), name='create'),
    # re_path(r'posts/in/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.SingleGroup.as_view(), name='single'),
    path('posts/in/<slug:slug>/', views.SingleGroup.as_view(), name='single'),
    path('join/<slug>/', views.JoinGroup.as_view(), name='join'),
    path('leave/<slug>/', views.JoinGroup.as_view(), name='leave')
]
```

groups/views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import (LoginRequiredMixin,
                                        PermissionRequiredMixin)
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from groups.models import Group, GroupMember

class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('name', 'description')
    model = Group

class SingleGroup(generic.DetailView):
    model = Group

class ListGroups(generic.ListView):
    model = Group


class JoinGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))

        try:
            GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user, group=group)
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.warning(self.request, ('Warning already a member'))
        else:
            messages.success(self.request, ('You are now a member'))
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class LeaveGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            membership = models.GroupMember.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user,
            group__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')
            ).get()
        except models.GroupMember.DoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, 'sorry you are not in this group')
        else:
            membership.delete()
            messages.success(self.request, 'You have left the group')
            return super().get(request, *args, *kwargs)
```

Comment: the issue is with your template file. there is most probably a typo there. please add it also to the question.

Comment: Yes. I’ve figured out that one of my templates calling contains a typo like { % url ‘<groups:xxx’ %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things maybe:

- `groups` does not appear in your `INSTALLED_APPS` parameter, is that normal?
- regarding your error log, it seems like you've got a typo in your template calling for `/groups/`. Check if you have the good quote type, and that also they are closed.

Comment: Installed app was normal but yes I’ve made a typo in one of my template calling.